# There is a way to use not operator in regex when ^ inside bracket is not an option?

Tags: php, regex

I went through dozen of already answered Q without finding one that can help me.

I have a string like this:

```
aaa.{foo}-{bar} dftgyh {foo-bar}{bar} .? {.!} -! a}aaa{
```

and I want to obtain a string like this:

```
aaa{foo}-{bar}dftgyh{foo-bar}{bar}-aaaa
```

Essentially I want to keep:

- valid word chars and hyphens wrapped in an open and a closed curly bracket, something that will match the regex `\{[\w\-]+\}`
- all the valid word chars and hyphens outside curly brackets

Using this:

```
$result = preg_replace( array( "#\{[\w\-]+\}#", '#[\w\-]#' ), "", $string );
```

I obtain the exact contrary of what I want: I remove the part that I want to keep.

Sure I can use `^` inside the square brackets in the second pattern, but it will not work for the first.

I.e. this will not work (the second pattern in the array is valid, the first not):

```
$result = preg_replace( array( "#[^\{[\w\-]+\}]#", '#[^\w\-]#' ), "", $string );
```

So, whis the regex that allow me to obtain the wanted result?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Which is the regex that I should use? Is not clear? I'm going to edit the qustion

Comment: if you have successfully written the regex to match the part you want, why not just go thru the matches, and concatenate the matched part together instead of replacing?

Comment: "valid word chars and hyphens wrapped in an open and a closed curly bracket, something that will match the regex \{[\w\-]+\}
all the valid word chars and hyphens outside curly brackets"... So all valid words and hyphens and curly braces? Why are you specifying inside and outside?

Comment: Because curly braces are valid and should be kept only if contain valid word. Otherwise, as you can see the expected result in OP, they should be removed. @Anthony

Comment: So really the rule is 1: all hyphens and words 2: any curly braces that enclose valid characters of rule 1?

Comment: @Anthony yes, exactly

Comment: For starters, `"#[^\{[\w\-]+\}]#"` is NOT doing what you think it is! You can't simply wrap _"expression"_ in square brackets with a leading caret (i.e. `[^expression]`), and expect it to match the opposite of _expression_. This `[^...]` syntax is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which simply matches one character that is NOT in the defined set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also an option to [(*SKIP)(*F)](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.0/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) the good stuff and do a `preg_replace()` with the remaining:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?:{[-\w]+}|[-\w]+)(*SKIP)(*F)|.~' , "", $str);
```

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fD5jU8/1); [eval.in](https://eval.in/192944)

Comment: Good one! That's the sort of regex *obscurities* (for me) that I imagined as the solution

Answer (score 4):

You may consider matching what you want instead of replacing the characters you do not want. The following will match word characters and hyphen both inside and outside of curly braces.

```
$str = 'aaa.{foo}-{bar} dftgyh {foo-bar}{bar} .? {.!} -! a}aaa{';
preg_match_all('/{[\w-]+}|[\w-]+/', $str, $matches);
echo implode('', $matches[0]);
```

Output as expected:

```
aaa{foo}-{bar}dftgyh{foo-bar}{bar}-aaaa
```

Comment: Sorry, I marked @jonny-5 as accepted because uses the function in OP, so seems to fit better as answer. Even if your logic is perfectly fine.